# MPI_Barrier() does not work on a small cluster

Tags: mpi

I want to use MPI_Barrier() in my programme, but there are some fatal errors.

This is my code:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include "mpi.h"
  3 
  4 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  5         int rank, size;
  6 
  7         MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  8         MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  9         MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
 10         printf("Hello, world, I am %d of %d. \n", rank, size);
 11         MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 12         MPI_Finalize();
 13 
 14         return 0;
 15 }
```

And this is the output:

```
Hello, world, I am 0 of 2. 
Hello, world, I am 1 of 2. 
Fatal error in PMPI_Barrier: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Barrier(425).........: MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Barrier_impl(331)....: Failure during collective
MPIR_Barrier_impl(313)....: 
MPIR_Barrier_intra(83)....: 
dequeue_and_set_error(596): Communication error with rank 0
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks and Regards!

Answer (score 2):

This generally reflects some sort of configuration error -- either host or username configurations are not consistent across nodes, or there is some sort of firewall blocking some ports.   The [MPICH2 FAQ](http://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/mpich2/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q%3a_My_MPI_program_aborts_with_an_error_saying_it_cannot_communicate_with_other_processes) discusses some places to look.