# MPI_Barrier doesn't work properly in Ubuntu

Tags: mpi

I'm a beginner in using MPI. Here I wrote a very simple program to test if MPI can run. Here is my hello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int numprocs, rank, namelen;
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  printf("Process %d on %s out of %d\n", rank, processor_name, numprocs);

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I use to node to test, the hostfile is: node1 node2

So I have two machines with name node1 and node2. I can ssh to each other without password.

I launch the program by typing: `mpirun -np 2 -f hostfile ./hello`.

The executable hello is in the same directory in both machine.

Then after I run, I get an error:

> Fatal error in PMPI_Barrier: Other MPI error, error stack:
>   PMPI_Barrier(425).........: MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
>   MPIR_Barrier_impl(331)....: Failure during collective
>   MPIR_Barrier_impl(313)....: MPIR_Barrier_intra(83)....:
>   dequeue_and_set_error(596): Communication error with rank 0 Fatal
>   error in PMPI_Barrier: Other MPI error, error stack:
>   PMPI_Barrier(425).........: MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
>   MPIR_Barrier_impl(331)....: Failure during collective
>   MPIR_Barrier_impl(313)....: MPIR_Barrier_intra(83)....:
>   dequeue_and_set_error(596): Communication error with rank 1

If I comment out the MPI_Barrier(), it can work properly. It seems the communication between machines has problem? Or I didn't install openmpi correctly? Any ideas?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10

I got some hints: This doesn't work well in MPICH2, if I use openmpi, then it works. I installed MPICH just by sudo apt-get install mpich2. Do I miss something? The size of mpich2 is much smaller than openmpi

Comment: 1) The computer names in hostfile need to be in separate lines, is that the case? 2) What is the program output if you comment the MPI_Barrier line? 3) How did you compile the program?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854879/mpi-barrier-does-not-work-on-a-small-cluster this sounds related

Comment: @RafaelReiter is right; this is generally a configuration issue.  Passwordless ssh between the two nodes is necessary, but MPIs generally also require a wide range of ports to be open, so check out any firewalls, iptables rules, etc: https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q:_My_MPI_program_aborts_with_an_error_saying_it_cannot_communicate_with_other_processes

Comment: I can use this program by using openmpi, so definitely it's nothing with the network. My hostfile is in separate lines.

Comment: I compile by mpicc -o hello hello.c

Comment: If I comment that line, it will output the correct rank

Comment: I found the reason. In hosts I have two 127.0.0.1, one is localcost, the other one is my real hostname. I change the one of my hostname to real IP and it works then

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/hosts, newer versions of some Linux distros add the following types of lines at the top of the file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 [hostname]
```

This should be changed so that the hostname line contains your actual IP address. The MPI hydra process will abort if you do not make this change with errors like:

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Barrier: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Barrier(425)...........: MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Barrier_impl(292)......: 
MPIR_Barrier_or_coll_fn(121): 
MPIR_Barrier_intra(83)......: 
dequeue_and_set_error(596)..: Communication error with rank 0
```